# Build Docker Container

Tags: docker, sbt, containers

In the context of a project, I have to run an sbt application in a Docker container.
That's why I created a Dockerfile, but when I try to build the container, I got an error but I don't understand why.

My code looks like this:

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN curl -LO "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v10.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz" && tar -xzf node-v10.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/local --strip-components=1  && rm node-v0.12.5-linux-x64.tar.gz

ADD app/abc/

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

CMD sbt plt/run

EXPOSE 9001
```

And that's the error:

`Sending build context to Docker daemon  745.3MB
Step 1/8 : FROM centos:latest
 ---> 49f7960eb7e4
Step 2/8 : RUN curl -LO "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v10.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz" && tar -xzf node-v10.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/local --strip-components=1  && rm node-v0.12.5-linux-x64.tar.gz -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
 ---> Running in d863c7cb398e
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nodejs.org; Unknown error
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -LO "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v10.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz" && tar -xzf node-v10.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/local --strip-components=1  && rm node-v0.12.5-linux-x64.tar.gz -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' returned a non-zero code: 6`

Did someone know what's the issue ?

Thanks a lot.

F.M

Comment: Did you read the message? curl can't resolve Nodejs.org. It might be easier to start with a node base image.

Comment: I don't understand, why curl couldn't resolve Nodejs.org ?

Comment: Did you fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The message `returned a non-zero code` means the command failed.

If you read the previous line, `curl` returned the following error: `Could not resolve host: nodejs.org; Unknown error`.

It means that during the build, you couldn't access to th "nodejs.org" hostname.

I also can't use your command line (I have the same error). You should follow [their documentation for installing Node.js for CentOS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora):

```
RUN curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - && yum -y install nodejs
```

If you can use another system than CentOS, you could use a [Node.JS base image from hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/).
In your Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8 (or another version)
```